# How to add an image to a question in a Javascript-Quiz?

Tags: javascript

This is the code of a basic quiz in javascript: https://codepen.io/Sulaimon-Olaniran/pen/zYKJLjK.

I would like to add a picture after a question but don't know how to do it.

```
<body onload="NextQuestion(0)">
    <main>
        <!-- creating a modal for when quiz ends -->
        <div class="modal-container" id="score-modal">
          
            <div class="modal-content-container">
              
                <h1>Congratulations, Quiz Completed.</h1>
              
                <div class="grade-details">
                    <p>Attempts : 10</p>
                    <p>Wrong Answers : <span id="wrong-answers"></span></p>
                    <p>Right Answers : <span id="right-answers"></span></p>
                    <p>Grade : <span id="grade-percentage"></span>%</p>
                    <p ><span id="remarks"></span></p>
                </div>
              
                <div class="modal-button-container">
                    <button onclick="closeScoreModal()">Continue</button>
                </div>
              
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="game-quiz-container">
          
            <div class="game-details-container">
                <h1>Score : <span id="player-score"></span> / 10</h1>
                <h1> Question : <span id="question-number"></span> / 10</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="game-question-container">
                <h1 id="display-question"></h1>
            </div>

            <div class="game-options-container">
              
               <div class="modal-container" id="option-modal">
                 
                    <div class="modal-content-container">
                         <h1>Please Pick An Option</h1>
                      
                         <div class="modal-button-container">
                            <button onclick="closeOptionModal()">Continue</button>
                        </div>
                      
                    </div>
                 
               </div>
              
                <span>
                    <input type="radio" id="option-one" name="option" class="radio" value="optionA" />
                    <label for="option-one" class="option" id="option-one-label"></label>
                </span>
              

                <span>
                    <input type="radio" id="option-two" name="option" class="radio" value="optionB" />
                    <label for="option-two" class="option" id="option-two-label"></label>
                </span>
              

                <span>
                    <input type="radio" id="option-three" name="option" class="radio" value="optionC" />
                    <label for="option-three" class="option" id="option-three-label"></label>
                </span>
              

                <span>
                    <input type="radio" id="option-four" name="option" class="radio" value="optionD" />
                    <label for="option-four" class="option" id="option-four-label"></label>
                </span>


            </div>

            <div class="next-button-container">
                <button onclick="handleNextQuestion()">Next Question</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </main>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
```

```
const questions = [
    {
        question: "How many days makes a week ?",
        optionA: "10 days",
        optionB: "14 days",
        optionC: "5 days",
        optionD: "7 days",
        correctOption: "optionD"
    },

    {
        question: "How many players are allowed on a soccer pitch ?",
        optionA: "10 players",
        optionB: "11 players",
        optionC: "9 players",
        optionD: "12 players",
        correctOption: "optionB"
    },

    {
        question: "Who was the first President of USA ?",
        optionA: "Donald Trump",
        optionB: "Barack Obama",
        optionC: "Abraham Lincoln",
        optionD: "George Washington",
        correctOption: "optionD"
    },

    {
        question: "30 days has ______ ?",
        optionA: "January",
        optionB: "December",
        optionC: "June",
        optionD: "August",
        correctOption: "optionC"
    },

    {
        question: "How manay hours can be found in a day ?",
        optionA: "30 hours",
        optionB: "38 hours",
        optionC: "48 hours",
        optionD: "24 hours",
        correctOption: "optionD"
    },

    {
        question: "Which is the longest river in the world ?",
        optionA: "River Nile",
        optionB: "Long River",
        optionC: "River Niger",
        optionD: "Lake Chad",
        correctOption: "optionA"
    },

    {
        question: "_____ is the hottest Continent on Earth ?",
        optionA: "Oceania",
        optionB: "Antarctica",
        optionC: "Africa",
        optionD: "North America",
        correctOption: "optionC"
    },

    {
        question: "Which country is the largest in the world ?",
        optionA: "Russia",
        optionB: "Canada",
        optionC: "Africa",
        optionD: "Egypt",
        correctOption: "optionA"
    },

    {
        question: "Which of these numbers is an odd number ?",
        optionA: "Ten",
        optionB: "Twelve",
        optionC: "Eight",
        optionD: "Eleven",
        correctOption: "optionD"
    },

    {
        question: `"You Can't see me" is a popular saying by`,
        optionA: "Eminem",
        optionB: "Bill Gates",
        optionC: "Chris Brown",
        optionD: "John Cena",
        correctOption: "optionD"
    },

    {
        question: "Where is the world tallest building located ?",
        optionA: "Africa",
        optionB: "California",
        optionC: "Dubai",
        optionD: "Italy",
        correctOption: "optionC"
    },

    {
        question: "The longest river in the United Kingdom is ?",
        optionA: "River Severn",
        optionB: "River Mersey",
        optionC: "River Trent",
        optionD: "River Tweed",
        correctOption: "optionA"
    },

]


let shuffledQuestions = [] //empty array to hold shuffled selected questions

function handleQuestions() { 
    //function to shuffle and push 10 questions to shuffledQuestions array
    while (shuffledQuestions.length <= 9) {
        const random = questions[Math.floor(Math.random() * questions.length)]
        if (!shuffledQuestions.includes(random)) {
            shuffledQuestions.push(random)
        }
    }
}


let questionNumber = 1
let playerScore = 0  
let wrongAttempt = 0 
let indexNumber = 0

// function for displaying next question in the array to dom
function NextQuestion(index) {
    handleQuestions()
    const currentQuestion = shuffledQuestions[index]
    document.getElementById("question-number").innerHTML = questionNumber
    document.getElementById("player-score").innerHTML = playerScore
    document.getElementById("display-question").innerHTML = currentQuestion.question;
    document.getElementById("option-one-label").innerHTML = currentQuestion.optionA;
    document.getElementById("option-two-label").innerHTML = currentQuestion.optionB;
    document.getElementById("option-three-label").innerHTML = currentQuestion.optionC;
    document.getElementById("option-four-label").innerHTML = currentQuestion.optionD;

}


function checkForAnswer() {
    const currentQuestion = shuffledQuestions[indexNumber] //gets current Question 
    const currentQuestionAnswer = currentQuestion.correctOption //gets current Question's answer
    const options = document.getElementsByName("option"); //gets all elements in dom with name of 'option' (in this the radio inputs)
    let correctOption = null

    options.forEach((option) => {
        if (option.value === currentQuestionAnswer) {
            //get's correct's radio input with correct answer
            correctOption = option.labels[0].id
        }
    })
   
    //checking to make sure a radio input has been checked or an option being chosen
    if (options[0].checked === false && options[1].checked === false && options[2].checked === false && options[3].checked == false) {
        document.getElementById('option-modal').style.display = "flex"
    }

    //checking if checked radio button is same as answer
    options.forEach((option) => {
        if (option.checked === true && option.value === currentQuestionAnswer) {
            document.getElementById(correctOption).style.backgroundColor = "green"
            playerScore++
            indexNumber++
            //set to delay question number till when next question loads
            setTimeout(() => {
                questionNumber++
            }, 1000)
        }

        else if (option.checked && option.value !== currentQuestionAnswer) {
            const wrongLabelId = option.labels[0].id
            document.getElementById(wrongLabelId).style.backgroundColor = "red"
            document.getElementById(correctOption).style.backgroundColor = "green"
            wrongAttempt++
            indexNumber++
            //set to delay question number till when next question loads
            setTimeout(() => {
                questionNumber++
            }, 1000)
        }
    })
}



//called when the next button is called
function handleNextQuestion() {
    checkForAnswer()
    unCheckRadioButtons()
    //delays next question displaying for a second
    setTimeout(() => {
        if (indexNumber <= 9) {
            NextQuestion(indexNumber)
        }
        else {
            handleEndGame()
        }
        resetOptionBackground()
    }, 1000);
}

//sets options background back to null after display the right/wrong colors
function resetOptionBackground() {
    const options = document.getElementsByName("option");
    options.forEach((option) => {
        document.getElementById(option.labels[0].id).style.backgroundColor = ""
    })
}

// unchecking all radio buttons for next question(can be done with map or foreach loop also)
function unCheckRadioButtons() {
    const options = document.getElementsByName("option");
    for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        options[i].checked = false;
    }
}

// function for when all questions being answered
function handleEndGame() {
    let remark = null
    let remarkColor = null

    // condition check for player remark and remark color
    if (playerScore <= 3) {
        remark = "Bad Grades, Keep Practicing."
        remarkColor = "red"
    }
    else if (playerScore >= 4 && playerScore < 7) {
        remark = "Average Grades, You can do better."
        remarkColor = "orange"
    }
    else if (playerScore >= 7) {
        remark = "Excellent, Keep the good work going."
        remarkColor = "green"
    }
    const playerGrade = (playerScore / 10) * 100

    //data to display to score board
    document.getElementById('remarks').innerHTML = remark
    document.getElementById('remarks').style.color = remarkColor
    document.getElementById('grade-percentage').innerHTML = playerGrade
    document.getElementById('wrong-answers').innerHTML = wrongAttempt
    document.getElementById('right-answers').innerHTML = playerScore
    document.getElementById('score-modal').style.display = "flex"

}

//closes score modal and resets game
function closeScoreModal() {
    questionNumber = 1
    playerScore = 0
    wrongAttempt = 0
    indexNumber = 0
    shuffledQuestions = []
    NextQuestion(indexNumber)
    document.getElementById('score-modal').style.display = "none"
}

//function to close warning modal
function closeOptionModal() {
    document.getElementById('option-modal').style.display = "none"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add an `imageUrl` key to your `questions` array, add the image in your HTML `<img id="question-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150">` and use `document.getElementById("question-image").src = currentQuestion.imageUrl;` to update it in your `NextQuestion` function, as shown below:

```js
const questions = [
    {
        question: "How many days makes a week ?",
        optionA: "10 days",
        optionB: "14 days",
        optionC: "5 days",
        optionD: "7 days",
        correctOption: "optionD",
        imageUrl: "https://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
    },

    {
        question: "How many players are allowed on a soccer pitch ?",
        optionA: "10 players",
        optionB: "11 players",
        optionC: "9 players",
        optionD: "12 players",
        correctOption: "optionB",
        imageUrl: "https://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
    },

    {
        question: "Who was the first President of USA ?",
        optionA: "Donald Trump",
        optionB: "Barack Obama",
        optionC: "Abraham Lincoln",
        optionD: "George Washington",
        correctOption: "optionD",
        imageUrl: "https://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
    },

    {
        question: "30 days has ______ ?",
        optionA: "January",
        optionB: "December",
        optionC: "June",
        optionD: "August",
        correctOption: "optionC",
        imageUrl: "https://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
    },

    {
        question: "How manay hours can be found in a day ?",
        optionA: "30 hours",
        optionB: "38 hours",
        optionC: "48 hours",
        optionD: "24 hours",
        correctOption: "optionD",
        imageUrl: "https://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
    },

    {
        question: "Which is the longest river in the world ?",
        optionA: "River Nile",
        optionB: "Long River",
        optionC: "River Niger",
        optionD: "Lake Chad",
        correctOption: "optionA",
        imageUrl: "https://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
    },

    {
        question: "_____ is the hottest Continent on Earth ?",
        optionA: "Oceania",
        optionB: "Antarctica",
        optionC: "Africa",
        optionD: "North America",
        correctOption: "optionC",
        imageUrl: "https://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
    },

    {
        question: "Which country is the largest in the world ?",
        optionA: "Russia",
        optionB: "Canada",
        optionC: "Africa",
        optionD: "Egypt",
        correctOption: "optionA",
        imageUrl: "https://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
    },

    {
        question: "Which of these numbers is an odd number ?",
        optionA: "Ten",
        optionB: "Twelve",
        optionC: "Eight",
        optionD: "Eleven",
        correctOption: "optionD",
        imageUrl: "https://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
    },

    {
        question: `"You Can't see me" is a popular saying by`,
        optionA: "Eminem",
        optionB: "Bill Gates",
        optionC: "Chris Brown",
        optionD: "John Cena",
        correctOption: "optionD",
        imageUrl: "https://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
    },

    {
        question: "Where is the world tallest building located ?",
        optionA: "Africa",
        optionB: "California",
        optionC: "Dubai",
        optionD: "Italy",
        correctOption: "optionC",
        imageUrl: "https://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
    },

    {
        question: "The longest river in the United Kingdom is ?",
        optionA: "River Severn",
        optionB: "River Mersey",
        optionC: "River Trent",
        optionD: "River Tweed",
        correctOption: "optionA",
        imageUrl: "https://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
    },


    {
        question: "How many permanent teeth does a dog have ?",
        optionA: "38",
        optionB: "42",
        optionC: "40",
        optionD: "36",
        correctOption: "optionB",
        imageUrl: "https://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
    },

    {
        question: "Which national team won the football World cup in 2018 ?",
        optionA: "England",
        optionB: "Brazil",
        optionC: "Germany",
        optionD: "France",
        correctOption: "optionD",
        imageUrl: "https://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
    },

    {
        question: "Which US state was Donald Trump Born ?",
        optionA: "New York",
        optionB: "California",
        optionC: "New Jersey",
        optionD: "Los Angeles",
        correctOption: "optionA",
        imageUrl: "https://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
    },

    {
        question: "How man states does Nigeria have ?",
        optionA: "24",
        optionB: "30",
        optionC: "36",
        optionD: "37",
        correctOption: "optionC",
        imageUrl: "https://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
    },

    {
        question: "____ is the capital of Nigeria ?",
        optionA: "Abuja",
        optionB: "Lagos",
        optionC: "Calabar",
        optionD: "Kano",
        correctOption: "optionA",
        imageUrl: "https://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
    },

    {
        question: "Los Angeles is also known as ?",
        optionA: "Angels City",
        optionB: "Shining city",
        optionC: "City of Angels",
        optionD: "Lost Angels",
        correctOption: "optionC",
        imageUrl: "https://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
    },

    {
        question: "What is the capital of Germany ?",
        optionA: "Georgia",
        optionB: "Missouri",
        optionC: "Oklahoma",
        optionD: "Berlin",
        correctOption: "optionD",
        imageUrl: "https://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
    },

    {
        question: "How many sides does an hexagon have ?",
        optionA: "Six",
        optionB: "Sevene",
        optionC: "Four",
        optionD: "Five",
        correctOption: "optionA",
        imageUrl: "https://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
    },

    {
        question: "How many planets are currently in the solar system ?",
        optionA: "Eleven",
        optionB: "Seven",
        optionC: "Nine",
        optionD: "Eight",
        correctOption: "optionD",
        imageUrl: "https://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
    },

    {
        question: "Which Planet is the hottest ?",
        optionA: "Jupitar",
        optionB: "Mercury",
        optionC: "Earth",
        optionD: "Venus",
        correctOption: "optionB",
        imageUrl: "https://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
    },

    {
        question: "where is the smallest bone in human body located?",
        optionA: "Toes",
        optionB: "Ears",
        optionC: "Fingers",
        optionD: "Nose",
        correctOption: "optionB",
        imageUrl: "https://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
    },

    {
        question: "How many hearts does an Octopus have ?",
        optionA: "One",
        optionB: "Two",
        optionC: "Three",
        optionD: "Four",
        correctOption: "optionC",
        imageUrl: "https://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
    },

    {
        question: "How many teeth does an adult human have ?",
        optionA: "28",
        optionB: "30",
        optionC: "32",
        optionD: "36",
        correctOption: "optionC",
        imageUrl: "https://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
    }

]


let shuffledQuestions = [] //empty array to hold shuffled selected questions

function handleQuestions() { 
    //function to shuffle and push 10 questions to shuffledQuestions array
    while (shuffledQuestions.length <= 9) {
        const random = questions[Math.floor(Math.random() * questions.length)]
        if (!shuffledQuestions.includes(random)) {
            shuffledQuestions.push(random)
        }
    }
}


let questionNumber = 1
let playerScore = 0  
let wrongAttempt = 0 
let indexNumber = 0

// function for displaying next question in the array to dom
function NextQuestion(index) {
    handleQuestions()
    const currentQuestion = shuffledQuestions[index]
    document.getElementById("question-number").innerHTML = questionNumber
    document.getElementById("player-score").innerHTML = playerScore
    document.getElementById("display-question").innerHTML = currentQuestion.question;
    document.getElementById("question-image").src = currentQuestion.imageUrl;
    document.getElementById("option-one-label").innerHTML = currentQuestion.optionA;
    document.getElementById("option-two-label").innerHTML = currentQuestion.optionB;
    document.getElementById("option-three-label").innerHTML = currentQuestion.optionC;
    document.getElementById("option-four-label").innerHTML = currentQuestion.optionD;

}


function checkForAnswer() {
    const currentQuestion = shuffledQuestions[indexNumber] //gets current Question 
    const currentQuestionAnswer = currentQuestion.correctOption //gets current Question's answer
    const options = document.getElementsByName("option"); //gets all elements in dom with name of 'option' (in this the radio inputs)
    let correctOption = null

    options.forEach((option) => {
        if (option.value === currentQuestionAnswer) {
            //get's correct's radio input with correct answer
            correctOption = option.labels[0].id
        }
    })
   
    //checking to make sure a radio input has been checked or an option being chosen
    if (options[0].checked === false && options[1].checked === false && options[2].checked === false && options[3].checked == false) {
        document.getElementById('option-modal').style.display = "flex"
    }

    //checking if checked radio button is same as answer
    options.forEach((option) => {
        if (option.checked === true && option.value === currentQuestionAnswer) {
            document.getElementById(correctOption).style.backgroundColor = "green"
            playerScore++
            indexNumber++
            //set to delay question number till when next question loads
            setTimeout(() => {
                questionNumber++
            }, 1000)
        }

        else if (option.checked && option.value !== currentQuestionAnswer) {
            const wrongLabelId = option.labels[0].id
            document.getElementById(wrongLabelId).style.backgroundColor = "red"
            document.getElementById(correctOption).style.backgroundColor = "green"
            wrongAttempt++
            indexNumber++
            //set to delay question number till when next question loads
            setTimeout(() => {
                questionNumber++
            }, 1000)
        }
    })
}



//called when the next button is called
function handleNextQuestion() {
    checkForAnswer()
    unCheckRadioButtons()
    //delays next question displaying for a second
    setTimeout(() => {
        if (indexNumber <= 9) {
            NextQuestion(indexNumber)
        }
        else {
            handleEndGame()
        }
        resetOptionBackground()
    }, 1000);
}

//sets options background back to null after display the right/wrong colors
function resetOptionBackground() {
    const options = document.getElementsByName("option");
    options.forEach((option) => {
        document.getElementById(option.labels[0].id).style.backgroundColor = ""
    })
}

// unchecking all radio buttons for next question(can be done with map or foreach loop also)
function unCheckRadioButtons() {
    const options = document.getElementsByName("option");
    for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        options[i].checked = false;
    }
}

// function for when all questions being answered
function handleEndGame() {
    let remark = null
    let remarkColor = null

    // condition check for player remark and remark color
    if (playerScore <= 3) {
        remark = "Bad Grades, Keep Practicing."
        remarkColor = "red"
    }
    else if (playerScore >= 4 && playerScore < 7) {
        remark = "Average Grades, You can do better."
        remarkColor = "orange"
    }
    else if (playerScore >= 7) {
        remark = "Excellent, Keep the good work going."
        remarkColor = "green"
    }
    const playerGrade = (playerScore / 10) * 100

    //data to display to score board
    document.getElementById('remarks').innerHTML = remark
    document.getElementById('remarks').style.color = remarkColor
    document.getElementById('grade-percentage').innerHTML = playerGrade
    document.getElementById('wrong-answers').innerHTML = wrongAttempt
    document.getElementById('right-answers').innerHTML = playerScore
    document.getElementById('score-modal').style.display = "flex"

}

//closes score modal and resets game
function closeScoreModal() {
    questionNumber = 1
    playerScore = 0
    wrongAttempt = 0
    indexNumber = 0
    shuffledQuestions = []
    NextQuestion(indexNumber)
    document.getElementById('score-modal').style.display = "none"
}

//function to close warning modal
function closeOptionModal() {
    document.getElementById('option-modal').style.display = "none"
}
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
  
html, body{
    height: 100%;
}


body{
    font-family: 'Montserrat', serif;
    
}

main{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: black;
    background: url('../assets/background_image.jpg');
    background-color : black;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.game-quiz-container{
    width: 40rem;
    height: 30rem;
    background-color: lightgray;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    border-radius: 30px;
}

.game-details-container{
    width: 80%;
    height: 4rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}

.game-details-container h1{
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.game-question-container{
    width: 80%;
    height: 8rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border: 2px solid darkgray;
    border-radius: 25px;
}

.game-question-container h1{
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 3px;
}

.game-options-container{
    width: 80%;
    height: 12rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.game-options-container span{
    width: 45%;
    height: 3rem;
    border: 2px solid darkgray;
    border-radius: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
span label{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: transform 0.3s;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: rgb(22, 22, 22);
}

span label:hover{
    -ms-transform: scale(1.12);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.12);
    transform: scale(1.12);
    color: white;
}

input[type="radio"] {
    position: relative;
    display: none;
}


input[type=radio]:checked ~ .option {
    background: paleturquoise;
}

.next-button-container{
    width: 50%;
    height: 3rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.next-button-container button{
    width: 8rem;
    height: 2rem;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: none;
    color: rgb(25, 25, 25);
    font-weight: 600;
    border: 2px solid gray;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
}
.next-button-container button:hover{
    background-color: rgb(143, 93, 93);
}

.modal-container{
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1; 
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    overflow: auto; 
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); 
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); 
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center; 
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1.2s ease-in-out;
    animation: fadeIn 1.2s ease-in-out;
}

.modal-content-container{
    height: 20rem;
    width: 25rem;
    background-color: rgb(43, 42, 42);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    border-radius: 25px;
}

.modal-content-container h1{
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    height: 3rem;
    color: lightgray;
    text-align: center;
}

.grade-details{
    width: 15rem;
    height: 10rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.grade-details p{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

.modal-button-container{
    height: 2rem;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.modal-button-container button{
    width: 10rem;
    height: 2rem;
    background: none;
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid rgb(252, 242, 241);
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
.modal-button-container button:hover{
    background-color: rgb(83, 82, 82);
}

@media(min-width : 300px) and (max-width : 350px){
    .game-quiz-container{
        width: 90%;
        height: 80vh;
     }
     .game-details-container h1{
        font-size: 0.8rem;
     }
 
     .game-question-container{
        height: 6rem;
     }
     .game-question-container h1{
       font-size: 0.9rem;
    }
 
    .game-options-container span{
        width: 90%;
        height: 2.5rem;
    }
    .game-options-container span label{
        font-size: 0.8rem;
    }
    .modal-content-container{
        width: 90%;
        height: 25rem;
    }
    
    .modal-content-container h1{
        font-size: 1.2rem;
    }
}

@media(min-width : 350px) and (max-width : 700px){
   .game-quiz-container{
       width: 90%;
       height: 80vh;
    }
    .game-details-container h1{
        font-size: 1rem;
    }

    .game-question-container{
        height: 8rem;
    }

    .game-question-container h1{
        font-size: 0.9rem;
     }

    .game-options-container span{
        width: 90%;
    }
    .modal-content-container{
        width: 90%;
        height: 25rem;
    }
    .modal-content-container h1{
        font-size: 1.2rem;
    }
}



@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity:1 ;}
  }

  @-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
  }
```

```html
<body onload="NextQuestion(0)">
    <main>
        <!-- creating a modal for when quiz ends -->
        <div class="modal-container" id="score-modal">
          
            <div class="modal-content-container">
              
                <h1>Congratulations, Quiz Completed.</h1>
              
                <div class="grade-details">
                    <p>Attempts : 10</p>
                    <p>Wrong Answers : <span id="wrong-answers"></span></p>
                    <p>Right Answers : <span id="right-answers"></span></p>
                    <p>Grade : <span id="grade-percentage"></span>%</p>
                    <p ><span id="remarks"></span></p>
                </div>
              
                <div class="modal-button-container">
                    <button onclick="closeScoreModal()">Continue</button>
                </div>
              
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="game-quiz-container">
          
            <div class="game-details-container">
                <h1>Score : <span id="player-score"></span> / 10</h1>
                <h1> Question : <span id="question-number"></span> / 10</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="game-question-container">
                <h1 id="display-question"></h1>
            </div>
            <img id="question-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150">

            <div class="game-options-container">
              
               <div class="modal-container" id="option-modal">
                 
                    <div class="modal-content-container">
                         <h1>Please Pick An Option</h1>
                      
                         <div class="modal-button-container">
                            <button onclick="closeOptionModal()">Continue</button>
                        </div>
                      
                    </div>
                 
               </div>
              
                <span>
                    <input type="radio" id="option-one" name="option" class="radio" value="optionA" />
                    <label for="option-one" class="option" id="option-one-label"></label>
                </span>
              

                <span>
                    <input type="radio" id="option-two" name="option" class="radio" value="optionB" />
                    <label for="option-two" class="option" id="option-two-label"></label>
                </span>
              

                <span>
                    <input type="radio" id="option-three" name="option" class="radio" value="optionC" />
                    <label for="option-three" class="option" id="option-three-label"></label>
                </span>
              

                <span>
                    <input type="radio" id="option-four" name="option" class="radio" value="optionD" />
                    <label for="option-four" class="option" id="option-four-label"></label>
                </span>


            </div>

            <div class="next-button-container">
                <button onclick="handleNextQuestion()">Next Question</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </main>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
```